# Packing multiple .exe in single .msi package

Tags: windows-installer

I am trying to put multiple .exe in single .msi package and It should be installed one by one.

lets say I have a.exe, b.exe and c.exe

On clicking on .msi package a.exe should be installed and the .msi should wait for it after successfully installation of a.exe it should trigger b.exe. On successful installation of b.exe , c.exe should be triggered for installation.

The .exe files (a.exe , b.exe and c.exe) are standard installables (for e.g.CodeSourcery, flash tools, IAR workbench etc).

Please let me know how to achieve this and what tools do I need.

Regards
Horaira

Comment: Please state what MSI builder you will use.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that a.exe, b.exe, and c.exe are installers?

Comment: I am planning to use advanced Installer. Ya a.exe, b.exe and c.exe are installers i want to package them in single package and its should be installed one by one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-convert-exe-to-msi.html) has some dedicated support for this. But it's a commercial tool, so a license is required.

As a free solution, you can try using [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) to create the MSI. You can then launch the EXE packages using [custom actions](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/authoring_custom_actions.htm).

Comment: Hi so can Advanced Installer fulfills above requirements.
Can it catch when one installation has been finished so that it can schedule next one?

Comment: Yes, it waits for the current installation to finish before launching the next one.

Comment: Thanks, What about Microsoft windows installer, Actually we have license for MS Visual Studio so I was thinking that any method to achieve this by using MS visual studio setup project.

Comment: Visual Studio is very limited when it comes to creating installers. For example, for what you need you would have to create XML manifests for each EXE, add them in a Visual Studio folder so they can be recognized and them add them as prerequisites to a setup project.

Comment: How to provide Command line interface just to show our deployed project version for example to know JRE version in window command prompt we type java -version and it shows the version, how to achieve this functionality in custom projects ?

Answer (score 5):

Those three EXE files may likely be MSI files inside EXE files. And running two MSIs simultaneously is problematic.

What you need is a bootstrapper EXE to launch each of the installers in sequence (in the same way that you would use a bootstrapper to install .NET before launching your own MSI install)

Examples:

- dotNetInstaller - http://dblock.github.com/dotnetinstaller/
- Burn (part of WiX) - http://wixtoolset.org/

Answer (score 3):

I think," Advanced Installer tool" is the bestfor such a case,I have tried packaging three different exe in one MSI package. It first bundles them up and then run the installation for them. Visual basic felt pretty difficult as compared to Advanced Installer.

Comment: is it possible with wix? Combining C++ and Python exes for creating msi