# Include TeamViewer.exe file in setup file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, setup-project, visual-studio-community

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 and want to include TeamViewer.exe or any other .exe file in project setup file as prerequisite.

When installing my setup file,it should check whether TeamViewer is installed on client machine or not.

if TeamViewer is not installed on client machine,then it should automatically install with my setup.

Comment: You should investigate and find out if you can legally distribute Teamviewer.exe. You may find that you cannot, and can get sued for doing so. Secondly, your question is unclear, because you aren't actually asking a question. Do you want your program to look for a file? Determine if a program is installed? Find a file in your build location? A combination of these things?

Comment: @Clay07g : I was unaware of including TeamViewer in my setup.But still ,I have 2-3 more .exe files to include in my project setup file like chrome standalone installer .I want to check on client machine, whether that TeamViewer or Chrome already installed on it and if not ,then find a file on my build Location and then install it offline.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008378/packing-multiple-exe-in-single-msi-package (not enough rep to make comment)...